# R: Substring after finding a character position?

Tags: regex, r, string

I have seen a few questions concerning returning the position of a character with a String in R, but maybe I cannot seem to figure it out for my case. I think this is because I'm trying to do it for a whole column rather than a single string, but it could just be my struggles with regex.

Right now, I have a `data.frame` with a column, `df$id` that looks something like `13.23-45-6A`. The number of digits before the period is variable, but I would like to retain just the part of the string after the period for each row in the column. I would like to do something like:

```
df$new <- substring(df$id, 1 + indexOf(".", df$id))
```

So `12.23-45-6A` would become `23-45-6A`, `0.1B` would become `1B`, `4.A-A` would become `A-A` and so on for an entire column.

Right now I have:

```
df$new <- substr(df$id, 1 + regexpr("\\\.", data.count$id),99)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you provide a few test cases? What you share here seems a bit over simplified and can be done very easily with `(g)sub` instead of `substr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @AnandaMahto mentioned his comment, you would probably be better simplifying things and using `gsub`:

```
> x <- c("13.23-45-6A", "0.1B", "4.A-A")
> gsub("[0-9]*\\.(.*)", "\\1", x, perl = T, )
[1] "23-45-6A" "1B" "A-A"
```

To make this work with your existing data frame you can try:

```
df$id <- gsub("[0-9]*\\.(.*)", "\\1", df$id, perl = T, )
```

Comment: Works great, thanks to you and @Ananda Mahato. I'm assuming that this means match a pattern of any length ending with a period and replace it with nothing?

Comment: This matches any number of leading numbers (0 through 9) followed by a single period, and then extracts and retains everything coming after it.

Answer (score 2):

another way is to use strsplit. Using @Tims example

```
    x <- c("13.23-45-6A", "0.1B", "4.A-A")
    sapply(strsplit(x, "\\."), "[", -1)

    "23-45-6A" "1B" "A-A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the characters including the `.` using

```
 sub('[^.]*\\.', '', x)
 #[1] "23-45-6A" "1B"       "A-A"
```

#### data

```
 x <- c("13.23-45-6A", "0.1B", "4.A-A")
```